# Unmarshall Nested XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have to unmarshal a XML to a POJO, but the XML structure is not nice and I couldn't find a way to accomplish that.

XML Structure:

```
<CURRENT_VALUES>
    <agency>
        <value xsi:type="xs:long" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">123</value>
    </agency>
    <company>
        <value xsi:type="xs:long" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1</value>
    </company>
    <channel>
        <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TEST</value>
    </channel>
</CURRENT_VALUES>
```

I created a POJO like this:

```
public class EventoModel 
{
    private String agency;
    private String company;
    private String channel;

    public String getAgency() {
        return agency;
    }

    public void setAgency(String agency) {
        this.agency = agency;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

The problem is the "value" element.
When I try to unmarshall, the POJO properties are empty (or null).

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EventoModel.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(outputter.outputString(xml));
EventoModel evento = (EventoModel) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML elements `<agency>`, `<company>` and `<channel>` have a rather complex nesting structure.
It is therefore much too simple to model them as Java `String` properties.

Instead, you need a separate POJO class for these.
Because the 3 have the same structure, we can use a common class for all of them.
Lacking a better name let's call this class `Ìtem`.
Notice that all 3 properties are annotated by [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CURRENT_VALUES")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventoModel 
{
    @XmlElement
    private Item agency;

    @XmlElement
    private Item company;

    @XmlElement
    private Item channel;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

The `Item` class can look like below.
It contains a property called `value`, modeling the XML element `<value>`.
Notice again, the property is annotated with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @XmlElement
    private Value value;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

The XML element `<value>` is still quite complex.
Therefore we need yet another POJO class for modeling it. Let's call the class `Value`.

The XML text between `<value ...>` and `</value>` is modeled by the property
`String text` which needs to be annotated with [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html).

The XML attribute `xsi:type="..."` is modeled by the property
`String type` which needs to be annotated by [`@XmlAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html).
Notice especially its `namespace` parameter which corresponds to the XML namespace
given by `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Value {

    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private String text;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

The screenshot below (taken from within the debugger) visualizes the over-all
Java structure and confirms that the unmarshalling works correctly:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm starting to work with XML in Java and you just helped me a lot!